# VC++ DHTML DIALOG move borderless form

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mouseevent, dhtml

I know how to move the borderless form in CDialog.I quoted my code as follows.

It enabled the window to move by dragging it by any point inside the window!

```
   void MyWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
   {
        PostMessage( WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM( point.x, point.y));
   }
```

What I need is how to move CDHTMLDialog borderless form.

Please respond as soon as possible.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will get the mouse click events in pretranslate message

```
 BOOL CSampleDlg::preTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
 {
     if(pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
     {
          PostMessage( WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM( pMsg->pt.x, pMsg->pt.y));
          return false;
     }
       return CDHtmlDialog::preTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try implementing the message handler OnNcHitTest and return HTCAPTION . This should work.

Thanks